# Displaying value of variable from jsx function in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I am very new to react and when I was trying out a simple addition function using variables, I was unable to display my output.

```
total= ()=>
    {
     let a=(variable:{this.props.id})
     let b=(variable:{this.props.id})
     let c=a+b
    }
render() { 
        return (  

            <div>



Total: {this.total(this.c)}

            </div>
        );
    }
}
 
export default Total;
```

Why is this happening ? Is there any other way to display the variables, because in my IDE (VS-Code), I am getting an error that "this code is unreachable".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you are not returning anything from `total` function. Also you don't need to pass `this.c` to `this.total` as `total` is a function that doesn't take arguments.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {a:1, b:2}
  }
  total(){
    return this.state.a + this.state.b
  }
  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        {this.total()}
      </div>
      );
    }
}


ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id='root'></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me Zeno.
The problem is that in my case, "a" and "b" are both properties of the previous frame, that is the "id" property. I just wanted to take a sum of the ids and display the output. I followed your code and altered it a bit like `this.state = {  a: ({param: this.props.id}), b: ({param: this.props.id}) }` . But, I am getting an output as "[object Object] [object Object]".

Comment: if you want to sum the ids you can use  `reduce`: `const sum = Object.entries(this.state).reduce((acc, [k, v])=>acc+v.param, 0)`. Here the docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

Comment: Ahh, thank you so much for your help. I finally figured out what was wrong with my code